# "Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined" javascript error in Django inlines.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

After updating Django to version 2.1.9 (from 1.9.8) I am receiving "Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined" javascript error on Django admin page when there are inline models.

The problem is in function `tabularFormset` in `inlines.js` file. This function takes two parameters: `function(selector, options)`. `options` here should have `prefix` param but it appears that `options` are undefined.

It looks like Django custom functions doesn't append `selector` as a first param, so `options` are first param. In result `options` param here is undefined.

Does anyone know what the problem might be here?

Comment: Did you execute `collectstatic` after upgrade? Do you have any modifications for django admin installed (custom fields, custom admin style, ordering, anything)?

Comment: @GwynBleidD I've found a problem. Had custom stacked template which has changed on newer django. I've just copier new template to my custom template and made necessary custom changes. Leaving that question so that maybe someone else will have such problem

Comment: Just ran into this problem, and thought I would comment. I was receiving the same error and traced it backed to DjangoTemplates backend in settings.TEMPLATES. I had `"autoescape": False`. Removing this fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the exact same error, was able to resolve by removing a customization of a Django template. I thought it was our code but it was a (meanwhile unnecessary) customization of https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline and just deleting the files from our project resulted in the original django versions being used automatically.